# IMU 10 DOF (D) dimension

Tags: pcb, imu, header

I got the dimension of the 10 DOF IMU model D on the internet. I wonder what is the dimension from the left to the center of the hole of the header pin. Besides that, for this type of header pin, the radius is 1.02mm, isn't it?
I tried to look for other pictures, but this is the best one that I could find.
Thank  you so much for your help!
[image: 10 DOF IMU dimension]

Comment: measure it with a ruler ... resize the image on your phone so that it is actual size ... then make measurements

Comment: Please provide a link to the module manufacturer's datasheet. Without that we can only guess.

Comment: https://www.waveshare.com/10-dof-imu-sensor-d.htm
https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/10_DOF_IMU_Sensor_(D)
these are the links from the manufacturer. This IMU contains several sensors so the datasheets are only about these sensors. They do not mention anything about the dimension of this IMU.

Comment: I tried to measure it by ruler, it is about 3mm but Is it accurate enough? I am afraid of it could be about 2.8 - 2.9mm